# How to get Key of Value that is greater than three Values above and below

Tags: c#, keyvaluepair, sorteddictionary

I've got a `sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<double,double>();`

And I'm trying to get the Key of the Value that is greater than the three Values above and three Values below but I don't know how.

sortedDict looks like this:

```
{
1.10 , 20
1.09 , 75
1.08 , 32
1.07 , 440 ------> This Value is greater than the Values of 3 keys above and below
1.06 , 200
1.05 , 160
1.04 , 130
1.03 , 250 ------> This Value is greater than the Values of 3 keys above and below
1.02 , 62
1.01 , 73
1.00 , 15
}

Output: (How do I get this?)
 1.07
 1.03
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted my earlier answer to post this. It's working code to do what you're asking

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<double, double>()
        { {
            1.10 , 20 },{
            1.09 , 75 },{
            1.08 , 32 },{
            1.07 , 440},{
            1.06 , 200},{
            1.05 , 160},{
            1.04 , 130},{
            1.03 , 250},{
            1.02 , 62 },{
            1.01 , 73 },{
            1.00 , 15 }
        };

        var totalLen = sortedDict.Count;
        for(var i = 0; i < sortedDict.Count; i++)
        {
            var val = sortedDict.ElementAt(i);

            if (i - 3 >= 0 && i + 3 < totalLen)
            {
                if (
                    sortedDict.ElementAt(i - 3).Value < val.Value &&
                    sortedDict.ElementAt(i - 2).Value < val.Value &&
                    sortedDict.ElementAt(i - 1).Value < val.Value &&
                    sortedDict.ElementAt(i + 1).Value < val.Value &&
                    sortedDict.ElementAt(i + 2).Value < val.Value &&
                    sortedDict.ElementAt(i + 3).Value < val.Value
                 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(val.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know how to get the key index for the sortedDict[] to be able to write it under a for argument... Currently the only thing I'm able to get is the Sum/Average/Max/Min of all Values under a foreach(KeyValuePair<double,double> pair in sortedDict)  Whenever I try to access the Keys above or below I get the error that the given key is not present in the dictionary.

Comment: I was able to get the keys `sortedDict.Keys.ElementAt(1)`